# XNA Framework Game Profile HiDef / Reach

Tags: xna, profile

You saw this question before but I can't understand the issue.

My graphic card was handling HiDef profile before I formatted my pc. I create a simple 2D game using XNA Game Studio 4.0 with HiDef profile. The game still exist at http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/?q=survival-zombie .

After formatted my pc, I installed graphic drivers of course and I installed VS2010 then XNA Framework but now my pc cannot handle Hidef profile even the game I developed before.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x64, Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Familied Graphic Card.

edit : I installed XNA Game Studio 4.0 not Framework. Framework comes with it.

solved: Previous driver works fine and solved my problem.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: "No suitable graphics card found."

Same error with the error on this link:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/error-on-new-xna-4-0-game-project-no-suitable-graphics-card-found

Comment: Are you sure the correct drivers are installed for your video card?

Comment: Not hundred percently sure but going to check again. Windows says "driver is up to date" and it was from manufacturer's lates driver.

Comment: I would try reinstalling it again then reboot your computer.

Comment: Done. Previous driver is working fine.

Comment: I have created an answer to reflect my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error**: "No suitable graphics card found."

**Solution**:If you are 100% sure you have the correct driver installed

- Reinstall the driver/s
- Reboot your computer
- Make sure your computer has acknowledged the installed driver
- Execute your XNA 4.0 game